# Using Sed to delete characters between the 10th character and the first period after the 10th

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I want to remove all characters between the 10th character of each line and the first period that comes after.

Say I have input that looks like

```
0123456789 foo. foo....
1234566789 bar. bar...
0912309299 foobar. foobar..
```

Output will be something like

```
0123456789. foo....
1234566789. bar...
0912309299. foobar..
```

Is there a sed command that does this?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is one way to make it:

```
$ sed -r 's/^([0-9]{10})[^.]*/\1/' file
0123456789. foo....
1234566789. bar...
0912309299. foobar..
```

Or also (to get 10 first chars in general, no matter if they are a number or not):

```
sed -r 's/^(.{10})[^.]*/\1/'
```

#### Explanation

- `-r` allow extended regex.
- `sed 's/find/replace/'` is the basic substitution: replace `find` with `replace` once. In this case, we use the following:
- `^([0-9]{10})[^.]*` catch first 10 digits. Also, catch all characters up to a dot `.`.
- `\1` print back the first block.

This is a schema of the substitution:

```
0123456789 foo. foo....
1234566789 bar. bar...
0912309299 foobar. foobar..
^^^^^^^^^^       ^^^^^^^^^^
     |    ^^^^^^^     |
     |         |      |
^([0-9]{10})  [^.]*   |
      |               |
      |          |----
^^^^^^^^^^-------------
0123456789. foo....
1234566789. bar...
0912309299. foobar..
```

Comment: @fedorqui . and the remaining characters are not captured by the group1 then how it prints the remaing part.

Comment: But i love this `sed 's/^\([0-9]\{10\}\)[^.]*\(\.\)\(.*\)$/\1\2\3/g' file`

Comment: No @potong, first 10 chars have to be caught and printed back. It is the chars in the middle up to the dot, the ones to delete.

Comment: @AvinashRaj check updated answer. Last part of the string is not even touched, that's why it "appears" again : )

Comment: @fedorqui your right `sed 's/^\(..........\)[^.]*/\1/' file` is what I should have written but what I meant to convey is the OP says `between the 10 character...` not the 10th integer.

Comment: @potong yes you are right, should be `.` instead of `[0-9]`. I just updated with that. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work.

```
sed -P 's/(?<=^.{10}).*?\.//'
```

**EDIT**: This is obviously wrong, as pointed out by Kent below, I mistakenly thought that sed supported `-P` for perl compatible regexes, this sent me down a rabbit hole of figuring out how to get perl compatible regexes in sed, one solution offered by kent was [ssed](https://launchpad.net/ssed/) but I didn't want to do that. long story short, here's the perl script:

```
perl -pe 's/(?<=^.{10}).*?(?=\.)//' example.txt
0123456789. foo....
1234566789. bar...
0912309299. foobar..
```

and [the post that sullied my hithertoo clean mind with perl knowledge](https://blogs.oracle.com/ksplice/entry/the_top_10_tricks_of). I'd never checked out perl but that's a handy post for when you want to extend your bash-fu just that little bit beyond `sed` or `awk`. As is obviously pointed out by the answer above me, none of this is necessary in this case, just for interest.

Comment: does your sed support `(?<=...)` ?

Comment: @Kent I'm just looking in the man page and can't find what happened to the `-P` flag I thought was there, I guess I'll delete this (I think I got confused with grep)

Comment: @Kent I couldn't ask you, I've been searching for a bit, do you know of a sed that does support pcre's?

Comment: yes, but I didn't give it a try: https://launchpad.net/ssed/  and be careful that the codes from ssed could not be portable.

Comment: +1 for learning perl to answer a question. That is fast learning, well done!!

Comment: @fedorqui thanks! I got [nerd sniped](http://xkcd.com/356/) by [pcre's](http://www.pcre.org/) and figured I had to go to the source to get some respite from my evil obsessive brain.

Answer (score 1):

For your data this `awk` gives correct output.

```
awk '{$2="";sub(/ /,".")}1' file
0123456789. foo....
1234566789. bar...
0912309299. foobar..
```

Just remove second field and change first space to a `.`